# How to change font in css?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I wanted to design a simple website but I've been struggling to change font. I looked many tutorial and read documentation but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong!

this is my html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My website</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
    <p class="par">Perchè non si riesce a cambiare font??</p>
</body>
```

and this is the style.css

```
 @font-face {
  font-family: 'Inter';
  font-style:  normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url("fonts/Inter-Regular.woff2") format("woff2"),
       url("fonts/Inter-Regular.woff") format("woff");
}

.par {
    font-size: 100px;
    font-family: Inter;
}
```

I can't really figure out how to make it work.

I'm currently testing it on windows 10 on Firefox and Chrome browsers (both updated)

Do you guys know what I'm doing wrong?

thanks!

Answer (score -4):

Make surge that the URL is correctly spelled.

Comment: I checked and it should be right